# Search and replace in Perl for particular word

Tags: perl

I have a huge file which consists of similar lines below , with different clocks:

```
cmd -quiet [get_ports p1] ref_clocks "cudtclk_sp cudtclk"

cmd -quiet [get_ports p2] clock "cu2xdtclk_sp cu2xdtclk"
```

And I need to replace cudtclk with some other name like cdtclk whenever I have ref_clocks in my file, globally.

I have written following code but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

sub clock_change 
{       # Get the subroutine's argument.
   my $arg = shift;
   # Hash of stuff we want to replace.
   my %replace = ( 
      "cudtclk" => "cdtclk",
   );

   # See if there's a replacement for the given text.
   my $text = $replace{$arg};

   if(defined($text)) {
      return $text;
   } 

   return $arg;
}

open PAR, "<file name>";
while(<PAR>) {
   $_ =~ s/\S+\s\S+\s\S+\s\S+\sref_clocks\s+(\S+\s+\S+)/clock_change($1)/eig;
   print $_;   ##print it to some file later.
}
```

Comment: You passed `"cudtclk_sp cudtclk"`, but your hash only contains `cudtclk`.

Comment: Also, your `s///` is replacing everything it matches, not just the parenthesized part.  So you're losing a lot of the line.

Comment: sorry squiguy, the edit was by mistake. I did not know how to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the substitution seems like unnecessarily complex, you can fix it with something similar to:

```
$_ =~ s/(ref_clocks\s+")([^_]+)_sp(\s+)\2/
     $1.clock_change($2)."_sp$3".clock_change($2)/eig;
```

Comment: </p>Hi, But I have  a situation in which the data is:</p>$v_cmd -quiet [get_ports cuclk_gtspine] ref_clocks "crclk_atop2xspine cuclk_gh2xspine cuclk_abot2xspine"

Answer (score 3):

"And I need to replace cudtclk with some other name like cdtclk"

```
perl -pe 's/\bcudtclk\b/cdtclk/' thefile > newfile
```

"whenever I have ref_clocks"

```
perl -pe 's/\bcudtclk\b/cdtclk/ if /\bref_clocks\b/' thefile > newfile
```

Alternatively:

```
# saves original file as file.bak
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\bcudtclk\b/cdtclk/ if /\bref_clocks\b/' file
```

Tighten to suit your data, as necessary.

Comment: I have something like this: $v_cmd -quiet [get_ports cuclk_gtspine] ref_clocks "crclk_atop2xspine cuclk_gh2xspine cuclk_abot2xspine" where i want to replpace all cuclk to cclk.I tried this:

Comment: `code` perl -pe 's/(\S+\s+)(\S+\s+)(\S+\s+)(\S+\s+)(\S+\s)(\")cuclk/$1$2$3$4$5$6cclk/ if /\bref_clocks\b/' test2 > test2_mod

Comment: This comment is for @JulianFondren